# error when compiling from a Terminal with a makefile

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

I am trying to recompile a command line program in Mac OS X 10.10. The last time I did this a few years ago it worked fine.  I now get the following error:

```
  HapList::Output(std::ostream&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const*, double, bool) in HapList2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [PHASE] Error 1
```

I am a novice at this and know very little really beyond typing "make" at the command line prompt.  Its clear it is something to do with the x86_64 architecture, but it compiled fine before under OS X Lion.  Does anyone have any clues how to fix this ?

Matt

Comment: `OS X Lion` used a different compiler (`gcc`), newer `OS X` uses `clang`. Maybe post your makefile, and/or more info about what you're compiling.

Comment: Stupid question but how do I post the makefile?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the function HapList::Output has been declared, but its definition (function body) has not been found during the build.

Locate where that function's definition resides and use that to work out why it's not being included in the build.